# Date reverts to current one in Windows Sandbox

Tags: windows, windows-10, date, windows-sandbox

I'm unable to change the current date in Windows Sandbox. I have disabled "Set time automatically" from the settings panel and I'm able to change the date, but 1 or 2 seconds later the date reverts to the current one.

This seems to be an issue similar to [Changing Windows 10 System Clock Doesn't Work](https://superuser.com/questions/1483586/changing-windows-10-system-clock-doesnt-work) but I don't know how to disable time synchronization for Win Sandbox.

Does anyone have any idea about how to keep this from happening?

Running

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
```

Picture of my date/time settings.
[image]

Misc:

- The windows time service is already disabled

Comment: This is expected behaviour, as it is working off of Hyper-V, and the Guest Additions are installed/activated automatically in Windows Sandbox.

Comment: Disable svc `Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service` inside the sandbox. See [this](https://superuser.com/a/1727928/290904) answer.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but I just stumbled upon this..
All you have to do is disable Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service inside the sandbox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not the perfect answer to this problem, But if you want to run software on a different date and time you can use RunAsDate application. This app is allowing you to run a specific software at different times and date and it works great on Windows Sandbox.
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html

Answer (score 0):

You need stop (and possibly disable) the `Windows Time` services from the Windows Services manager.

Start > run > `services.msc`

Look for `Windows Time`

Right-click and `Stop` or
right-click and go to `Properties`, then change the `Startup type` to disabled.

Comment: Looked it up and that's not the solution in my case, Windows Time is already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Very crude, but seems to work.  Copy/paste into Powershell ISE

for ($num=1; $num -lt 9999999999; $num++){
sleep -Milliseconds 500
set-date 12/22/21
}

Adjust timing as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jony Adamit's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1727928/69492): Create the text file below on the host (extension: `.wsb`), then double-click to launch the Sandbox.

`no_time_sync.wsb`

```
<Configuration>
  <LogonCommand>
    <Command>net stop "Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service"</Command>
  </LogonCommand>
</Configuration>
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-configure-using-wsb-file#creating-a-configuration-file