# date reverts to current date after changing it

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, date-time

I have a VirtualBox VM running an x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04. Whenever i try changing the date to a previous date (in my case 5 days ago), the date always reverts back to the current date a few seconds later.

Here's what i've done:

I disabled both network connections in the VM so it won't sync.
In the settings panel, i disabled all sync'ing.

I've tried:

- changing the date in the settings panel
- `sudo date +%d --set="21"`
- `sudo date -s "5 days ago"`
- `sudo timedatectl set-time 2022-04-21`
- `systemctl stop time-sync.target`
- `systemctl stop time-set.target`

I've seen mentions of the hardware clock, but i get this:

```
hwclock --show
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --verbose option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

so i assume the VM isn't emulating one. I have no running processes or installed packages that match "*ntp*".

What is restoring my date?

Rebooting didn't help.

(FYI i have a Windows VM that has a similar behavior, also with network disconnected.)

**Edit 1**

I noticed this in `/var/log/syslog` after changing time:

```
Apr 26 14:18:36 myvm kernel: [ 5336.382332] 13:18:36.743879 timesync vgsvcTimeSyncWorker: Radical guest time change: 432 002 205 702 000ns (GuestNow=1 650 979 116 743 855 000 ns GuestLast=1 650 547 114 538 153 000 ns fSetTimeLastLoop=true )
```

followed by a bunch of anacron jobs, none apparently related to time...

**Edit 2**

[This](https://superuser.com/a/539881) answer suggests that indeed VirtualBox is forcing the date, but disabling this, even with reboots, didn't help; the date always reverts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run two commands with the VM shut down.

The first is:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
```

For the second command, calculate first the number of milliseconds
between your chosen date and the present.

For example, for the date `2003-06-06`, open PowerShell and enter:

```
([datetime]"06/06/2003" - [datetime]::Now)
```

Keep the `TotalMilliseconds` value and enter the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Virtual Machine" --biossystemtimeoffset <TotalMilliseconds-value>
```

Source:
[How to set the BIOS date in VirtualBox](https://winaero.com/how-to-set-the-bios-date-in-virtualbox/).

Comment: Yup, so i noticed and answered.

Answer (score 0):

The command mentioned:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
```

must be run with the VM shut down, otherwise it won't take effect. You can double-check by searching for `GetHostTimeDisabled` in the .vbox XML file of the VM (usually in `C:\Users\your.username\VirtualBox VMs\YourVM\YourVM.vbox` in a windows host).