# Can't change date on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to change date in System Settings:

[image]

when I press "Change" button the date is changed, but it is changed back to the current date within a second or two.

Comment: Enable the two settings for Time Zone and Time.  No Time Zone is likely the issue.

Comment: What if you use Control Panel -> Date settings rather than Windows Settings app?

Comment: If you use VirtualBox, then you may try to [disable time synchronization](https://superuser.com/questions/539880/using-virtual-box-is-it-possible-to-set-your-virtual-machine-time-to-be-differen): `VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1`